# Can we use Google Drive to embed Mathematica CDF demonstrations in the new Google Sites?

Tags: google-drive, google-sites

I am concerned here with the exact premise of the following question on Mathematica Stack Exchange:

[How to embed a Mathematica demonstration in Google sites](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38026/how-to-embed-a-mathematica-demonstration-in-google-sites)

The very-helpful top-voted answer already explains the Mathematica notebook to CDF file conversion, as well as the creation of the Index HTML file, with the appropriate file entry.

However, the answer talks about maintaining both these files, cdf and Index.htm  "into a folder on the server". Sorry for a noob question, but I can't find a way of doing this, where is this folder supposed to be located?

Here's what I tried: I tried using the "From (Google) Drive" option in the Insert tab, maintaining one folder in the drive itself which contained both the Index and the cdf file. 
[image]

But apparently, this doesn't seem to be the folder that the answer above seems to be referring to.

Can someone enlighten me with how exactly is supposed to be accomplished? (Note: there is no real compulsion to necessarily use only Google Drive to the desired end, alternatives will be greatly appreciated.)